# confluent local service failed in schemargeistry

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to start confluent local services start and its failed while starting schema registry

`JAVA_HOME is /usr/local/opt/openjdk@11`

confluent 7.3.2

`export CONFLUENT_HOME=/Users/adminuser/confluent-7.3.2`
export PATH="${CONFLUENT_HOME}/bin:$PATH"

```
~ » confluent local services start                                                                                                                                                                          ramana@mbp
The local commands are intended for a single-node development environment only,
NOT for production usage. https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html

Using CONFLUENT_CURRENT: /var/folders/k8/sd8b8dnn5n956nbdy4npjcyw0000gn/T/confluent.019095
Starting ZooKeeper
ZooKeeper is [UP]
Starting Kafka
Kafka is [UP]
Starting Schema Registry
Error: Schema Registry failed to start
```

and error in confluent local services sr log is

```
`[2023-03-18 19:45:47,156] ERROR [kafka-store-reader-thread-_schemas]: Error due to (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStoreReaderThread:76)
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.SchemaException: Buffer underflow while parsing response for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=FETCH, apiVersion=13, clientId=KafkaStore-reader-_schemas, correlationId=9)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStoreReaderThread.doWork(KafkaStoreReaderThread.java:302)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:99)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.SchemaException: Buffer underflow while parsing response for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=FETCH, apiVersion=13, clientId=KafkaStore-reader-_schemas, correlationId=9)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.parseResponse(NetworkClient.java:826)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.handleCompletedReceives(NetworkClient.java:970)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:652)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:280)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:251)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1311)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1247)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1173)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStoreReaderThread.doWork(KafkaStoreReaderThread.java:197)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at java.base/java.nio.Buffer.nextGetIndex(Buffer.java:651)
    at java.base/java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.getInt(HeapByteBuffer.java:402)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.ByteBufferAccessor.readInt(ByteBufferAccessor.java:43)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.message.ResponseHeaderData.read(ResponseHeaderData.java:95)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.message.ResponseHeaderData.<init>(ResponseHeaderData.java:67)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.ResponseHeader.parse(ResponseHeader.java:71)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.AbstractResponse.parseResponse(AbstractResponse.java:109)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultClientInterceptor.parseResponse(NetworkClient.java:1531)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.parseResponse(NetworkClient.java:819)
    ... 9 more
[2023-03-18 19:45:47,156] INFO [kafka-store-reader-thread-_schemas]: Stopped (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStoreReaderThread:66)
[2023-03-18 19:46:46,095] ERROR Error starting the schema registry (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication:77)
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.exceptions.SchemaRegistryInitializationException: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.exceptions.SchemaRegistryTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for join group to complete
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.init(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:334)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.initSchemaRegistry(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:75)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.configureBaseApplication(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:90)
    at io.confluent.rest.Application.configureHandler(Application.java:285)
    at io.confluent.rest.ApplicationServer.doStart(ApplicationServer.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain.main(SchemaRegistryMain.java:44)
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.exceptions.SchemaRegistryTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for join group to complete
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.leaderelector.kafka.KafkaGroupLeaderElector.init(KafkaGroupLeaderElector.java:211)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.init(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:329)
    ... 6 more`
```

not sure what am I missing?

I have tried to destroy and restarted, still no luck

Comment: What happens if you run `schema-registry-start` directly instead of using `confluent` command?